# How to make v-skeleton-loader inside v-for in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to show a `v-skeleton-loader` in Vuetify. I have used `v-if` and `v-else`. If the image is not loaded, then it should show the skeleton loader. Otherwise, it should should show the image. This is my code:

```html
<template>
  <v-col v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" cols="6">
    <v-lazy :options="{ threshold: 0.5 }" min-height="130">
      <v-hover v-slot="{ hover }">
        <v-card id="options_card" link width="160">
          <v-sheet v-if="!images" class="px-3 pt-3 pb-3">
            <v-skeleton-loader max-width="300" type="image"></v-skeleton-loader>
          </v-sheet>
          <v-img
            v-else
            id="thumbnail"
            width="100%"
            height="130"
            :src="option.thumbnail"
          ></v-img>
        </v-card>
      </v-hover>
    </v-lazy>
  </v-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      images: false,
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.images = true
  },
}
</script>
```

But the `v-skeleton-loader` is not seen on the screen.

Comment: I mean do you make async call to api?

Comment: cause setting images to true in mounted doesn't make sense, since it will be always true when component renders in dom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`VImage` has a [`placeholder` slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/#placeholder) that would be used for customizing the loader component to be shown while the image is loading:

```html
<v-img>
  <template v-slot:placeholder>
    <v-sheet>
      <v-skeleton-loader />
    </v-sheet>
  </template>
</v-img>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OJMjvNz?editors=1010)

Answer (score -2):

```
<v-img>
  <template v-slot:placeholder>
    <v-sheet>
      <v-skeleton-loader />
    </v-sheet>
  </template>
</v-img>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please explain how it solves to issue. Putting code alone is not good practice.