# Nuxt, Vuetify skeleton loader while image loads

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I cannot find one proper example of loading an image with a skeleton loader. I'm using nuxt + Vuetify and I'm trying to use a simple image with a skeleton loader.

Here is my code.

```html
<template>
  <v-skeleton-loader v-if="loading" :loading="loading" type="image">
    <v-card
      v-show="loaded"
      class="ma-auto elevation-4"
      shaped
      color="darkgreen"
      width="500"
      flat
    >
      <v-img
        src="/products/em-lucky-combo.jpg"
        max-width="500"
        @load="hasLoaded"
      >
      </v-img>
    </v-card>
  </v-skeleton-loader>
</template>
```

my method

```html
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    hasLoaded() {
      console.log('Image finished loading')

      this.loading = false
      this.loaded = true
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

But as I said the method never gets called when it is inside the `v-card` tag or directly in the skeleton loader.

I have tried using `@load`, I have tried using mounted hooks like below.

```html
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    const readyHandler = () => {
      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        console.log('Document Rendered')
        this.loading = false
        this.loaded = true
        document.removeEventListener('readystatechange', readyHandler)
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', readyHandler)

    readyHandler() // in case the component has been instantiated lately after loading
  },
}
</script>
```

But nothing seems to work properly or elegantly. Is it just not possible? The moment the `<v-img>` tag is inside the skeleton loader or inside a `v-card` inside a skeleton loader it never gets rendered no matter what I do. One suggestion was to use a slot. I'm guessing it has something to do with slots but I do not understand how to use these.

I tried doing something like this.

```html
<template v-slot:default>
  <v-card
    class="ma-auto elevation-4"
    shaped
    color="darkgreen"
    width="500"
    transition="fade-transition"
    flat
  >
    <v-img
      src="/products/em-lucky-combo.jpg"
      max-width="500"
      transition="fade-transition"
      @load="imageLoaded"
    ></v-img>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

I tried using the code below.

[How to make v-skeleton loader inside v-for in Vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62609009/8816585)

```html
<v-img>
  <template #placeholder>
    <v-sheet>
      <v-skeleton-loader />
    </v-sheet>
  </template>
</v-img>
```

Comment: Not sure about the whole thing (hard to visualize directly) but you should probably use the `fetch()` hook in pair with `$fetchState.pending`, it's a [nice helper](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/fetch#nuxt--212) that Nuxt provides. Making a `v-if` on it to display a skeleton, then showing the other content in a `v-else` should be totally functional.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would I do something like this then @load="$fetch"

Comment: Wait, actually you are not loading an external image. Why do you even need a skeleton here? Since the image is local, you should not have any waiting time per-se.

Comment: Well, there is a very small delay I agree, I'm just trying to stop the image from popping in which is quite noticeable. Would you suggest not using a skeleton loader at all?

Comment: I guess, I just really want this to work and figure it out. And I'm just confused as to where the image tag should be, outside or inside the skeleton loader tags.

Comment: It's popping and [moving some content](https://web.dev/optimize-cls/#images-without-dimensions) the issue or you do want to have [some blur](https://using-gatsby-image.gatsbyjs.org/blur-up/) while it's loading? None of those are skeleton per-se. [Skeletons](https://buefy.org/documentation/skeleton) are used mainly to have some placeholder until some API content is being fetched (like on Facebook/Instagram).

Comment: Yes, the big issue is that after the page is finished loading I have this image pop into screen. I guess I can fix that with image dimension but on a slower connection my images do take a little longer to display so I have this white space just sitting there. Would like to give some kind of indication. But maybe I should rather try blurring..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, OP had enough of using just some dimensions and a lazy loader image. Since images were local, there was no need for a skeleton.

```html
<template>
  <v-card class="ma-auto elevation-4" flat shaped width="500">
    <v-img
      aspect-ratio="1"
      class="grey lighten-2"
      lazy-src=""
      max-height="350"
      max-width="500"
      src="/"
      transition="fade-transition"
    >
      <template v-slot:placeholder>
        <v-row
          align="center"
          class="fill-height ma-0"
          justify="center"
        >
          <v-progress-circular
            color="grey lighten-5"
            indeterminate
          ></v-progress-circular>
        </v-row>
      </template>
    </v-img>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kissu I realised my approach was wrong and unnecessary . I ended up giving my images some set dimensions and using a lazy image loader with a placeholder slot which works just fine. As he mentioned my images are loaded locally so it wont really work in my case.

What I did in the end.

```
<template>
  <v-card class="ma-auto elevation-4" flat shaped width="500">
    <v-img
      aspect-ratio="1"
      class="grey lighten-2"
      lazy-src=""
      max-height="350"
      max-width="500"
      src="/"
      transition="fade-transition"
    >
      <template v-slot:placeholder>
        <v-row
          align="center"
          class="fill-height ma-0"
          justify="center"
        >
          <v-progress-circular
            color="grey lighten-5"
            indeterminate
          ></v-progress-circular>
        </v-row>
      </template>
    </v-img>
  </v-card>
</template>
```